# Send groupchat message using xmpp framework & quickblox server iOS

Tags: ios, quickblox, xmppframework

I'm working on chat room using quickblox server and XMPP framework for iOS. I'm able to join room successfully. However, When I try to send message it says: Insufficient privileges to send groupchat message.

Below is the response that I receive from quickblox XMPP server:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="chatroom1@muc.chat.quickblox.com" type="error" to="11130377-33829@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-198215"><body>hfg</body><subject>GroupNameSubject</subject><error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></forbidden><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" lang="en">Insufficient privileges to send groupchat message.</text></error></message>
```

P.S I'm not using quickblox SDK for iOS.

Comment: could you please share what are you sending ?

Comment: @HarvantS. <message type="groupchat" to="chatroom1@muc.chat.quickblox.com"><body>test message</body><subject>GroupNameSubject</subject></message>

Comment: well as per your error message you are not in the MUC Room. Read here http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#associations Table 3

Comment: @HarvantS. Yes, I go through it and realize that I can't even join room as I don't have privileges. How can I set the privileges to join room?

Comment: Only "Moderator" can change privileges or by default all members should moderators. You can invite user to join with a privilege (when creating a room) or when any new user join the room you can change its affiliation (only moderators can do).

Comment: Mind one thing "Roles" and "Affiliations" are different things. Study well the document. Everything you want is there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Quickblox chat you need to use Quickblox iOS SDK. And there is no another way.

You can follow their complete guide here: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API